# If Avraham had a healing stone why did he need an angel to heal him?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, medicine, avot-patriarch-fathers, vayera

The Gemara in [Baba Basra, Tes Zayin Amud Beis](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=16b&format=pdf) says Reb Shimon says that Avraham had a stone that he wore around his neck that healed the sick. If so why did he need a angel to come down to heal him ([Rashi Bereshit 18:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8213/showrashi/true#v2))?

Comment: if i remember correctly, the gamoroh says that when Avrohom Ovinu passed away, HaShem took the stone and placed it to hang under the sun. i dont know which famous star is located under the sun but maybe it refers to that, and people in that community in which the tanna/amora lived in believed that star had healing powers. also the gamoroh says that its a famous saying, as the day goes by the sickness becomes weakened. now regarding the angel, RaMbaM holds that those angels were not angels but prophets. I am not sure that he says one prophet came to heal Avrohom Ovinu. the kashya is on Rashi.

Answer (score 10):

The Gemara there is discussing verse [24:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219#v1):

> א. וְאַבְרָהָם זָקֵן בָּא בַּיָּמִים וַי־הֹוָ־ה בֵּרַךְ אֶת אַבְרָהָם בַּכֹּל:
>
> 1. And Abraham was old, advanced in days, and the Lord had blessed Abraham with everything.

The different Rabbis are giving different interpretations how Avraham was blessed.

This didn't happen until after Sarah passed away, which was 37-38 years after Avraham's circumcision.

So a simple answer would be that Avraham didn't use the stone to heal himself after his circumcision because he did not possess it yet.

Comment: The Apirion from the Baal Kitzur Shulchan Aruch gives this as one of his answers I just saw it as you gave it

Comment: link to the Apirion: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39731&pgnum=18 - He also mentions that the Maharsha gives another reason, but I haven't looked it up.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Moshe Feinstein explains in the Darash Moshe that Avraham could have just prayed to be healed. The reason why he did not is because he loved the pain of the mitzvah. (Whatever that means.)